# Need Second word from string. How to do?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one string variable which contains "Welcom salathia"... 
I want to store store salathia to another string.... how to do this in asp.net using vb.net

Comment: What constitutes a word - is anything that does not contain whitespace a word?

Comment: Did you try my answer.? i have one doubt.! Does that variable contains only the string "Welcom salathia" or it contains some other too.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1:**

```
Dim s As String = "Welcom salathia"
s = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray)(1)
```

**Way 2:**

```
Dim s As String = "Welcom salathia"
s = s.substring(s.index(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and get the second string.

```
Dim s As String = "Welcom salathia"
' Split string based on spaces
Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {" "c})
```

Comment: Dim txt_addedbyuser As String = Welcome_id.Text
Dim string_split As String = txt_addedbyuser.Split(New Char() {" "c})     Displays an error 'value of type 1-D array of string cannot be converted to string'

Comment: in vb.net you can also write:  Dim words As String() = Split(s, " ")

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains function to get first space and its index and then get the characters till the next space is found.

Split function can also be useful in this mater. and it would be easier way too.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are runs of spaces

```
    Dim s As String = "Welcom   salathia"
    ' Split string based on spaces, gurad against runs of space
    Dim words() As String = s.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Debug.WriteLine(words(1)) 'show second word
```